# Why do I see blank debug logs in an org?

Tags: apex, debugging, developer, logging

Can someone explain why I cannot see any logs in my debug logs? Looks completely blank? This is a production org and I'm looking at the logs in a managed package

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as a client, or as the ISV? You can't normally see managed package logs directly, but instead need to submit a case to have this feature enabled.

Comment: Logged in as a user but we were able to see the SOQL queries and how far the execution has gone. Not sure this time nothing is being shown.

Comment: This is strange. I think you need to create the ticket with Salesforce. As long as you setup the debug log correctly (I mean time window and the user), you should be able to see the debug log here.

Comment: What are your TraceFlag and DebugLevel settings like? Does really basic logging from something like Anonymous Apex appear?

Comment: It should at least show who the log is for and when it was created. It looks like an SF issue to me. I've been using this logging settings for years.

Comment: @DavidJ Quite possibly, yes. Does it show up in the developer console logs section? Just looking for something to help isolate the issue.

Comment: I look at the "debug logs" section on the platform and it is there. Can't check developer console unfortunately, because it happened a while ago and we cannot trigger the same scenario at will.

Comment: This may sound silly but have you checked by scrolling to the right because your page looks very wide.

Comment: Haha! I tried scrolling down and right! It's totally blank!